# How to use Symfony Vardumper to avoid displaying relationships

Tags: symfony, dump, var-dump

How to use Symfony Vardumper to avoid displaying relationships

Is is possible that even when the relationships are there avoiding to display those relationships? with a limiter or something?

Thanks you. Been searching for this for a while

Comment: AFAIK that's not possible.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know at least an option to fold the endless results like for the browser. I am var dumping from a cli command line

Comment: have you checked this: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper/advanced.html ?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a `__debugInfo` method on your objects returning an array with only the keys you want to display or (if you don’t own the code of the objects you want to dump) you have to create a custom object caster and register it on the `var_dumper.cloner` service.

In this second case, the symfony debug-bundle must be registered, then you can create your own caster function.

In the caster function you can even customize the class name displayed for your object using the `$stub` (3rd) parameter.

use Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Cloner\Stub;

Ex:

```php
<?php
function obj_caster($object, $array, Stub $stub, $isNested, $filter)
{
    // ... populate $array or unset some keys ...

    return $array;
}
```

See the documentation here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper/advanced.html